# nodejs + ejs for if express returns a unexpected catch

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, ejs

im sure this is silly, but i cant get it to work for the life of me, i just want to do a simple for statement with an if inside on ejs, but it keeps returning a unexpected catch event in express.

to set up the scene, i've got a JSON thats setting up a a registration form in nodejs using ejs as my template renderer, lets say I have  the following code:

```
var userData:{
        "username":"User name",
        "email":"johndoe@gmail.com",
        "password":"Please enter Password",
        "birthdate":"date"
        }
```

and i have a ejs file that goes

```
<h1 id="page-title"><%= title %></h1>
<div id="list">
<form action="user/create/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div class="item-new">
    <% for (var key in userData){ %>
        <% if(key != 'birthdate'){ %>
        <input class="input" type="text" name="<%= key %>"  placeholder="<%= userData[key] %>"/>

        <% }else{ %>
        //do something
    <%  } %>

</div>
```

i've tried to define a variable beforehand and check the value of the definitions

Comment: ok, so i think i might have figured it out... seems since im parsing my json from an external file I cant access it's keys, i re didi the example and applied a:

var obj = userData.toJSON(userData);

i'll check this update on this actual case and if it works i'll post the entire code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the example you provided is indeed all of your code, you aren't closing all of your tags, specifically, you aren't closing your for loop, one of your divs, or your form. When I close all of these, the view will render for me without errors. This is the ejs that I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style-min.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1 id="page-title"><%= title %></h1>
  <div id="list">
    <form action="user/create/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div class="item-new">
          <% for (var key in userData){ %>
            <% if(key != 'birthdate'){ %>
              <input class="input" type="text" name="<%= key %>"  placeholder="<%= userData[key] %>"/>
            <% } else{ %>
            <% } %>
          <% } %>
        </div>
     </form>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I used this function to render it:

```
exports.test = function(req, res){
  res.render('test', { title: 'nodejs + ejs for if express returns a unexpected catch', userData:{
        "username":"User name",
        "email":"johndoe@gmail.com",
        "password":"Please enter Password",
        "birthdate":"date"
        }});
};
```

When I use the above I get this as a result:
[image]

Comment: thanks!, the code i posted was a condensed version to get the idea across, my problem was when referencing the external JSON. thank you my friend.